# File Input(storing a file)

Tags: python, file, input, storage

I wrote this code that prompts user to enter five different test scores, then saves it to tests.txt but when I go to open the file tests.txt , it only shows the last number that was input instead of all five numbers. Anything wrong with my code that is causing that??

Here is the code:

```
scorefile=open('test.txt','w')

for count in range(1,6):

    print('Please enter test scores')

    score=input('Test score:')

scorefile.write(str(score) + '\n')

scorefile.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because the writing of the scores to the file happens *outside* the loop, meaning that only the last value is written.

You need to move that line *inside* the loop so that *every* score is written:

```
scorefile=open('test.txt','w')
for count in range(1,6):
    print('Please enter test scores')
    score=input('Test score:')
    scorefile.write(str(score) + '\n')
scorefile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file with the option `'w'`, you will overwrite the old file each time. Instead, open it in append mode, using

```
open('test.txt','a')
```

EDIT: @paxdiablo pointed out the write in the question is outside of the loop, and because of this my answer won't work. However, if you close the file, then want to add to it later, you can use the append mode.